# What is an access control graph?

Tags: security, access-control

A question I came across describes a scenario of an information system in a clerical office and states-

"Identify the sets of S={subjects}, O={objects} and P={privileges} for the above
systems of the manufacturing organisation, and model the case using an access
control graph."

Further, the question says-

"Your graph should indicate links representing
overriding or modifying operations."

What is a access control graph? I came across the following 2 diagrams, the latter depicts the BLP model. Which one should be used in this context?

[image]

[image]